# Android - How would it be possible to make a ListView to mimic the android notifications ListView programmatically?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am looking to build a ListView that looks identical to Android notifications, programmatically. I am not sure how to customize every row of the list. Should it be a list of WebViews?

```
ArrayAdapter<String> modeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, stringArray);
    modeList.setAdapter(modeAdapter);
```

In the above code, what do I need to replace the stringArray with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see the [examples](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/index.html) for listveiw